# Solve for coefficients $a,b,c$ of $(2ax+3bx^2+4cx^3)(ax^4+bx^5+cx^6-x^5) + ax^2 + bx^3 +cx^4 - x^2 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for coefficients $a,b,c$ of $$(2ax+3bx^2+4cx^3)(ax^4+bx^5+cx^6-x^5) + ax^2 + bx^3 +cx^4 - x^2 = 0$$

I'm reading a book on differential equations where we begin finding the center manifold of a system of differential equations, and I've come across a section I don't completely understand. In an effort to reverse engineer the solution, I attempted to work through the example and unfortunately I'm at a loss of how they jump to the solution of the following equations involving unknown constant coefficients:

> "Setting the coefficients of like powers of $x$ equal to zero yields $a - 1 = 0$, $b = 0$, $c = 0$, $\ldots$"

What exactly do they mean by "*setting the coefficients of like powers of* $x$"? I unfortunately don't see exactly how to identify what is a *like power* in this case. Obviously we can factor this whole mess out and equate coefficients that way, but it's preferable not to. Or is this the only way to pick out the coefficients?

Comment: What is being asked is: $0 + 0 \, x + 0 \, x^2 + \cdots + 0 \, x^9 = (a-1) \, x^2 + b \, x^3 + \cdots$. In this case $a-1 = 0$, $b=0$, etc..

Comment: @Leucippus, most definitely, but how exactly do we come to the conclusion that the coefficient of $x^2$ is $(a-1)$? Other than expanding and then factoring again, I see no other way unfortunately.

Comment: Just by looking at what the expansion might be, there is no way that another $ x^2 ,x^3 or x^4 $ would show up, so by saving us the trouble of having to expand we get $a=1,b=0,c=0$

Comment: @pyrazolam Expansion is about the only clear way to make sure all terms have been accounted for. The printed version of mathematics is nice, but the behind the print part is messy and lengthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the only way to solve a problem like this would be to expand out the full expression and combine like terms.

But sometimes there are shortcuts.

Note that in the second parenthesis, all terms are $x^4$ or higher powers, and those in the first are $x^1$ or higher - resulting in a product consisting only of $x^5$ terms and higher (to see this more clearly, factor out the $x$ and $x^4$ respectively).

So the only terms in lower powers are those final terms after the parenthetical product, and these by themselves provide enough information to calculate a, b and c.

Similar shortcuts in other problems may involve spotting that a given product results only in even or odd powers, and finding enough information in the more easily accessible terms provided after the product.